# Multiple insert statement with same variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to perform several SQL INSERT statements with the same value to multiple tables? For example, I am passing a ID and want to INSERT those into 4 tables. All tables share the same primary key, as table 2, table 3 and tabl 4 contain sub-properties of table1 elements.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id)
  VALUES ($phpVar);
INSERT INTO table 2 (id)
  VALUES ($phpVar);
INSERT INTO table 3 (id)
  VALUES ($phpVar);
INSERT INTO table 4 (id)
  VALUES ($phpVar);
```

Further how could I bundle those into one statement, to prevent DB data failure during crashes etc?

Comment: 1) Why not try it and see? 2) Transactions...

Comment: `$phpVar` is using injection, **this is dangerous**. Use proper parameterization instead

Comment: You can create a stored procedure with input parameter which insert the same value into these tables